# How to validate product combination on 'checkout_cart_add' event in Magento?

Tags: magento, e-commerce

It's definitely a new business rule for Magento.

“you must have a product A or/and B in YOUR SHOPPING CART, in order to add other products”

Does anyone have an idea how to implement this?

I was looking at http://markshust.com/2012/08/27/create-checkout_cart_product_add_before-observer-magento but instead of before event I would create "after" then do check there using

```
$totalItemsInCart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
```

and delete products if A or B is not in the list.

Do you think it would be the right approach?

and another question.  How do I pass message from observer to frontend (/checkout/cart/) saying "Sorry you cannot bla bla bla because of bla bla bla"?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach sounds reasonable, however I would prefer to make use of sales_quote_add_item observer.

To throw an error message, use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError('Your error message here');
```

En redirect them afterwards:

```
$this->_redirect('path/to/page/');
```

Comment: What is the difference between sales_quote_add_item and checkout_cart_add? And another question.  I don't use $this->_redirect('path/to/page/'); and I let page go to /checkout/cart/. I use your suggestion for message Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError('Your error message here'); but don't see it at /checkout/cart/ page.  Do I have to load some block?

Comment: basically I need event name when cart is modified.

Comment: Try: $this->_redirect('checkout/cart/');